# How do i get second list combined with first list with some formatting in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists with me :

```
fs :
[['fs', 'gd', 'sd'], ['at', 'ae', 'ale', 'eh'], ['bt', 'is']]

wd :
['ae', 'gd', 'cs']
```

I need to display the data from fs next to wd based on the condition that the element from wd matches the one in fs and in case, there's no match, still the element shall appear.
In this case, the desired out put should be :

```
ae: at,ale,eh
gd: fs,sd
cs:
```

here's something that i've tried but this is not getting me the value in the third line in output i.e. `cs:`

```
for q in range(0,len(wd)-1):
    for r in range(0,len(wd)-1):
        if wd[q] in fs[r]:
            fd = wd[q]
            fsn = fs[r]
            fson = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(fd,''),fson))
            fson.remove("")
            ffson = str(fson)
            print(fd+': '+ (ffson))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would get you every element and would be a bit more pythonic.

```
fs = [['fs', 'gd', 'sd'], ['at', 'ae', 'ale', 'eh'], ['bt', 'is']]
wd = ['ae', 'gd', 'cs']

for element in wd:
    counterparts = []
    for i in fs:
        if element in i:
            for elem in i:
                if elem != element:
                    counterparts.append(elem)

    print(f'{element}: {",".join(counterparts)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```python
res = {}
for first_list_element in wd:
    found = False
    for second_list_element in fs: 
        if first_list_element in second_list_element:
            found = True
            fs.remove(second_list_element)
            second_list_element.remove(first_list_element)
            res[first_list_element]=second_list_element
    if not found:
        res[first_list_element] = []
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some edge cases to handle but I think this should work for you:

```
output = {}
for q in wd:
    for r in fs:
        if q in r:
            output[q] = [item for item in r if item != q]
            break
        else:
            output[q] = []

print(output)
```